# PostgreSQL: Select material with all its parent categories

Tags: postgresql, parent-child, with-clause

I have two tables

Categories

- Id
- Name
- ParentCategoryId (reference to `Categories` table column `Id`)

Materials

- Id
- Name
- CategoryId (reference to `Categories` table column `Id`)

I want to select specified material and all its parent categories

Categories table data

```
 Id  Name                 ParentCategoryId
------------------------------------------
  1  food                 null
  2  fruits               1
  3  exotic fruits        2
  4  IT equipment         null
```

Materials table data

```
 Id Name             CategoryId
 -------------------------------
  1  mango            3
```

When I select mango which is `Id=1`, I want to get in my result set all related categories of this material (food, fruits, exotic fruits)

I wrote something like this by using recursive with clause

```
WITH RECURSIVE RecursiveCTE AS
(
    SELECT m."Id", m."Name", c."Id" as "CategoryId", c."Name" "CategoryName"
    FROM "Materials" m
    INNER JOIN "Categories" c on c."Id" = m."CategoryId"
    WHERE m."Id" = 1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT rt."Id", rt."Name", c."Id" as "CategoryId", c."Name" "CategoryName"
    FROM RecursiveCTE rt
    INNER JOIN "Categories" c ON c."ParentCategoryId" = rt."Id"
)
SELECT * FROM RecursiveCTE
```

Comment: the level of hierarchy is unknown. so it should select data until the parentId is null

Answer (score 1):

resolved )))

```
WITH RECURSIVE RecursiveCTE  AS(
    SELECT m."Id", m."Name", c."Id" as "CategoryId", c."Name" as "CategoryName", c."ParentCategoryId"
    FROM "Materials" m
    INNER JOIN "Categories" c on c."Id" = m."CategoryId"
    where m."Id" = 1

    union all

    SELECT rt."Id", rt."Name", c."Id" as "CategoryId", c."Name" as "CategoryName", c."ParentCategoryId"
    FROM RecursiveCTE rt
    INNER JOIN "Categories" c on c."Id" = rt."ParentCategoryId"
    WHERE rt."ParentCategoryId" is not null
)
SELECT * FROM RecursiveCTE
```

Comment: Why UNION ALL? May be you want to exclude duplication rows with UNION?

Comment: @Irina Nothing wrong with `UNION ALL`, it's more efficient not needing to check for duplicates. It will work fine if categories form a tree structure, that is, not a graph with circles.